# how to make /usr/lib owned by root again

Tags: 12.04, sudo, root, chown

I chowned -R username /usr/lib and now i cannot sudo or do any thing really due to sudoers.so belonging to username.

How do i fix this and make /usr/lib owned by root again?

Answer (score 1):

1. Reboot the system to enter `grub`. Select recovery mode. Enter root shell
2. Remount the system with read/write permissions: `mount / -o rw,remount`
3. Run `chown -R root:root /usr/lib`. Once done, reboot.

Comment: This is not right..not all the direcories/files under `/usr/lib` are `root` owned so simply running `chown` again won't resolve this..this is a failrly complex situation..

Comment: @heemayl I've ran `ls -l /usr/lib/* | less` all files are owned by root. group ownership was all root, except `drwxr-xr-x   2 root utempter     4096 Feb 18 21:48 utempter`. For that directory the group ownership was root. That's all. This should fix most of the problem

Comment: You are doing recursion..there are thousands of files under that sublevel..how can you be sure of them all?

Comment: `find /usr/lib -ls | awk '{print $5" "$6}' | grep -v root   ` also no problem

Answer (score 0):

Try with one of the following :

```
sudo chown [USERNAME]:root /usr/lib
```

Or

```
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/lib
```

Use option `-R` with `chown` if its just for recursive.

Comment: sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins

this is the error it gives me. I also cannot boot into recovery mode by holding shift. I think its because this instalation has been done on top of a w8 OEM laptop.

any ideas?

Comment: No. Someone has given that file ownership to the user with `chown` without -R. Before reinstall, just try with `pkexec chown root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so` or `pkexec chmod go-w /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy!
Boot with Instalation CD (Ubuntu), and go to /media/ubuntu/(your disk Ubuntu), then execute:

```
sudo chown root -R /usr/lib
```

Comment: This is not right..not all the direcories/files under `/usr/lib` are `root` owned so simply running `chown` again won't resolve this..this is a failrly complex situation..